# Can you push rockwool through a joist cavity for 10 feet without breaking the rockwool?

Tags: drywall, insulation, basement-insulation

I'm wondering how brittle rockwool is.  If I have a last 3 feet exposed in my drywall ceiling with 15 foot long joist bays, can I push the Rockwool through the rest of the 12' of joist cavity?  I heard that you can wrap it in a plastic bag to push it through and then pull the plastic bag out.

Would doing this just crush the rockwool if it's brittle?  Or, would it just expand to fit.

I'm hoping that I don't have to just bite the bullet and open up the entire ceiling.

Comment: Is this for sound or thermal insulation (or both)? If the latter, it's more about precision placement than breakage.

Comment: It is not brittle.  It is similar to fiberglass batts or a stiff pillow.  It is usually placed as a friction fit(tight).  It should be as much fun as stuffing a pillow in a too small pillow case.

Comment: @isherwood, for thermal insulation

Comment: Don't tell me down here. Tell the community in your question post.

Comment: What is above the ceiling? Any chance you could slide the batt in at an angle (so it fits between the joists) then encourage it to lay flat after it's in place? Or maybe folded in half, tented up and held with strings that are cut and removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having just insulated some new construction work with Rockwool, I doubt you'd actually be able to push it more than a few inches into the cavity.

It would slide nicely along the drywall "floor", but it should be a friction fit against the joists and it just won't slide against the wood. It'll grab and hold and additional pushing will just bunch it up until you push hard enough to push your hand through the batt, tearing it up.

The stuff can be cut easily with a steak knife (my wife picked up a package of very high end, 4-for-$1 steak knifes at a local "everything's super cheap" store) and they worked very well. Some pieces were also torn off, sometimes on accident, sometimes on purpose.

You can give it a try, but plan on having to pull the ceiling down, friction fit the batts between the joists, then experience the joy of hanging drywall over your head. (Just did that part, too - *oh* so much fun!)

Comment: So you did not use those new fancy dandy drywall lifts?

Comment: Used a drywall lift to help my FIL install tin ceiling panels in his barn, 12' off the ground, 25 years ago. Couldn't fit a lift into the small spaces we added on. Just used ladders and a couple of strong, young backs - it was the least they could do for 18 years of free room & board. :)

Answer (score 4):

There are various densities for rockwool, from very soft to quite hard, but I believe rockwool batts are the wrong material to solve your problem.

If you want to inject insulation through a small opening, consider blown insulation.

[image]

This guy is blowing fiberglass, I did the same in my attic. Many materials can be blown: rockwool, fiberglass, cellulose, polystyrene, etc.

The insulating material is sold in large bags. You need a blower, and a pipe that will reach the end of the cavity you want to fill. It's really easy to do.

To insulate between joists you would make a hole at one end to allow the air to exit, and blow at the other end, which fills the entire space between the joists. But if you use a rigid PVC pipe to reach into the space and blow insulation starting  from the far end, you can also do it with only one end accessible.

Another advantage of blown insulation is it flows around pipes, cables, etc that may be in the way and prevent you from pushing more "solid" material.